# Not loading desktop from login screen

Tags: login-screen

I was using Ubuntu 12.10 for quite a long time. But from a few days back, I am unable to go to the desktop. The Ubuntu is loaded and the login screen is shown. Even after entering the password, the desktop is not loaded, but the same screen is visible and I am unable to click on anything even though I can move the  mouse pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, press CTLR+ALT+F1, then type your user name and password.

After that, you should type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, type your password and wait the package to download and to install.

After the install completes, press CTLR+ALT+F7 to go back to the LightDM login screen, things should be working again.

I hope this solution works.

Comment: No, I tried it-its showing me that the package is has been already installed and that its new

Comment: Did you try to reconfigure the package? (you can do it by typing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop`). Also, you can try to install another display manager (such as gdm, which can be installed by typing `sudo apt-get install gdm`).